# Where is the closest free beach where free camping is permitted to Georgia, the country?

Tags: camping, georgia-country, beaches, nudism, black-sea

When winter is over in Tbilisi and I can start hitchhiking again it would be good to find a nice warm [free beach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_beach) to camp on for a while.

I know there is Vama Veche on the Black Sea in Romania, but are there closer places? Maybe in Bulgaria or Russia?

I've heard there were efforts to start a nudist beach on the Black Sea in Georgia but I haven't read any recent updates so I supposed the plan has not progressed?

I've also hear that somebody is trying to open the first naturist resort in Turkey but I assume it doesn't include a free beach.

Or might Greece be better since it's also only two countries away and being further south should warm up earlier?

Comment: Being not familiar with the terminology, I read this as you were looking for a beach and camp ground where you don't have to pay. But judging from the tags, you looking for a beach and camp ground that is free of clothing, correct? From the title this is not obvious to everybody.

Comment: Oh sorry "free beach" is a lower key word for a nude beach as the Wikipedia article redirects to it - I'll add a link. Free camping means camping where you pay nothing but typically have no facilities either. So both.

Comment: have you considered a free-camping wiki? like hitch wiki, it may get some niche popularity.

Comment: You mean have I considered making one? Or is there an existing one I should consider using?

Comment: And re-noticed the comments.  I meant have you considered making one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silistart in Bulgaria

[Google map of the beach very close to the Turkish border](http://maps.google.com/?ll=42.019075,28.027153&spn=0.031819,0.084543&t=h&z=14)

Comment: Looks like the name might be Silistar or Sinemoretz... do you have a link for any more information on it? It looks good so I'm googling a lot right now...

Comment: This is definitely the closest, but I haven't been able to confirm that I can camp there for free, and my Romanian friends are expressing doubts. Can you confirm, preferably with a link, that camping for free is okay there?

Comment: I can confirm that on silistar , sinemoretz and for definetly sure on irakli beach you can camp...in best conditions.

Answer (score 2):

There are some more in Romania: beaches at [Neptun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptun), [Costineşti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costine%C5%9Fti), [2 Mai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Mai) and [Vama Veche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vama_Veche) sea resorts, on the Black Sea.

Further north in the Ukraine there are several too:

(Crimea)

- [Koktebel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koktebel), formerly known as Planerskoye. Located in South-Eastern Crimea.
- [Lisya buhta](http://Lisya%20buhta), remote place in South-East of Crimea. Popular summer place of nudists, ravers and rastamans. The location boasts an annnual month-long techno party.

(Odessa)

- [Chkalovsky Nudist Beach](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chkalovsky_Nudist_Beach&action=edit&redlink=1), located south of Delfin beach and north of [Arcadia beach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadia_beach)

(Kiev)

- [Dovbychka](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dovbychka&action=edit&redlink=1) clothing-optional beach, located on [Trukhaniv Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trukhaniv_Island) in front of Hidropark ([map](http://toolserver.org/~geohack/geohack.php?pagename=List_of_social_nudity_places_in_Europe&params=50_27_2_N_30_34_8_E_region%3aUA_scale:10000))
- Obolon naturist beach, located south of yacht club ([map](http://toolserver.org/~geohack/geohack.php?pagename=List_of_social_nudity_places_in_Europe&params=50_31_40_N_30_31_51_E_region%3aUA_scale:10000))

[Nudist World](http://en.nudist-world.org/index.php?page=map) shows quite a few, but in that region really only the Koktebel one as mentioned before.  And Primorsko further south.

Finally [Naked and Active](http://www.naktiv.net/maps/) also has maps, and shows a few beaches in Bulgaria that may suit...

Comment: Are you sure that camping free of charge is possible at Neptun and Costineşti? The former is now totally overdeveloped and the latter is now totally overrun - but maybe there are parts at the furthest ends of these beaches. None of your links seem to say anything about it though. I know it's possible at 2 Mai and Vama Veche though at the latter it's theoretically not allowed it turns out you can't camp at all in the centre, then further down you must pay and supposedly receive some security and/or amenities, and further still the police will warn you it might not be secure but it's free.

Comment: Ah crud, I was treating it as 'free' camping as in 'free beach' - ie nude.  Lousy homonyms. Well at least now we have a list of beaches, it's just a case of working out which ones cost.

Comment: Yeah sorry Mark I tried to make it clear that I wanted both in some of the early comments and also in the bounty notes.